# Identifying faulty component in AC-DC regulated PSU

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, rectifier, zener

I'm debugging this faulty AC-DC power supply circuit, which is meant to output 24 V DC from a 240 V AC supply. The 24 V line is actually about 10.1 V under load.
[image: Schematic]

I have tested ZD1 and ZD2 which seem to be fine. There are two components that I'm suspecting now:

1. C1 only measures 0.25u when it should be 0.68u. Is this likely to cause a problem? The right hand side of C1 is at 13 V rms which is less than I would have expected.
2. D3 has a DC voltage drop of 10.1 V, whilst D1, D2 and D4 each have voltage drops of 5.3 V. I know this is not a very meaningful measurement, but does the different voltage on D3 indicate a problem with it?

I don't have replacement components on hand so I would like to try and work out the problem without trial and error. Can anyone confirm/refute my ideas above?

Comment: And that load is . . . ?  What is the required peak output current?

Comment: @AnalogKid I would estimate less than 100 mA... it powers a microcontroller, a relay and some LEDs for a coffee machine. The theoretical current for the design value of C1 is about 50 mA, so I would expect significantly less than that actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even before reading that C1 was measuring low, my immediate thought was that C1 is probably the problem.

This circuit is what's called a capacitive dropper, a circuit that uses the reactance of a capacitor to drop most of the line voltage without incurring the losses a resistor would. The capacitor's reactance has to be low enough to allow through the necessary current, though--and if the capacitance drops, the reactance rises. So if your capacitor is measuring less than half its nominal value, I'd expect the output voltage to drop significantly.

Try replacing C1. Make sure it's a properly rated capacitor--a class X or class Y cap would be best here, as they're designed to fail open, never short.

And *always remember*: Capacitive droppers are *not* isolated from mains, and should *never* be used where there's *any* risk of any contact with the circuit they power. You might think it's perfectly safe because it's only 24 V, but this circuit can easily be deadly.

Comment: Did you remove C1 from circuit to test it.  Probably the 200k resistors across it will upset a meter.

Comment: @ronsimpson The resistors would increase the reading on simple capacitance meters, not decrease it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get a replacement for C1. After reading about capacitive droppers that makes sense.

Comment: @ronsimpson Yes I removed it, it was about the same either way.

Comment: @nasci I see you accepted this answer; does that mean replacing C1 worked?

Comment: @Hearth Yes, I replaced C1 and it's working fine now. Thanks for your help. I think the voltage is still a bit low, about 22 V, but everything works okay. As someone else pointed out below, there are several design flaws that could cause this.

Answer (score 1):

100 mA is a lot of current for a capacitive drop power supply.  At 50 Hz, a 0,68 uF capacitor is acting like a 4.7 K resistor.

Rough estimate - C1 is too small.  To push 100 mA through a 0.68 uF cap, the input would have to be over 450 V.  If C1 is only 0.25 uF, the problem is even worse.  As shown, the input section equates to 4.62 K.  If you decrease R5 to 51 ohms (to draw 100 mA) and recalculate, you will see that the circuit is current-starved by the input section.

D1 - D4 are simple rectifiers.  The forward voltage drop (Vf) across them should be approx. 0.8 - 0.9 V.  Anything else is either a component error (like a zener instead of a rectifier), a wiring error, or a component failure.

UPDATES:

R4 is too large.  At 100 mA load current, the voltage drop across R4 would be 47 V.  Given that the voltage at this point is supposed to be only 24 V, that's a problem.  Even if the 24 V node were actually a clean, flat 24 Vdc, the output would be less than half the desired 5.1 V.

C2 is too small.  If the circuit did not have such a large impedance at its input, and was being driven by a power transformer, at 100 mA load current the ripple voltage on C2 is approx. 4.5 Vpeak-to-peak.  But your circuit has an additional 4.6K impedance in series with C2, so its peak voltage is way short of 24 V.  Basically, C1 and C2 form a large voltage divider.

You do not say what you are using to measure the 24 V node, but that 10.1 V value has a significant amount of AC ripple in it.  This is a yet another component of why the 24 V node does not measure not 24 V.

I'm curious - given that all of these errors are EE101 topics and grade school arithmetic, why did anyone think this design was ready to build?